# how can I optimize this filtering method in vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, optimization, filter

I would like to optimize a method which I use to decide which values to display in a tale.
I have a table that shows different values, and on top of it, there are some input fields. The values selected in the input field are used to filter the content of the table.

```
<!-- the input fields-->
<v-select placeholder="Index" :options="indexList" v-model="filterTable['indexedValue']" @input="filteringTable"></v-select>
<v-select placeholder="Domain" :options="domainList" index="index" label="txt" v-model="filterTable['domainValue']" @input="filteringTable"></v-select>
<!-- table -->
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="(value, i) in filteringTable()" :key="value.id">
          ...<!-- values shown here-->
</table>
```

The values selected in the input fields are bounded to the object filterTable.

```
data () {
  return {
    filterTable: {}
  }
}
```

And the method that is called on input is defined as follows:

```
filterTable () {
      var newLinks = this.links // object containing all the info we want to show in the table

      if (this.filterTable['indexedValue'] != null && this.filterTable['indexedValue'] !== undefined) {
        newLinks = newLinks.filter(l => l.post.indexed === this.filterTable['indexedValue'])
      }
      if (this.filterTable['domainValue']) {
        newLinks = newLinks.filter(l => l.tag.domain === this.filterTable['domainValue'])
      }

      return newLinks
    }
```

(my code has 2 more if statements that check value given by some other input fields, but they also follow the same logic above)
This code works and it does filter the table, but as you can see there are two many if statements in it and I am wondering if there are some ways I can follow to make it more efficient/optimized?

Any advice is highly appreciated!

Comment: what is `this.filterLinkTable`

Comment: hey, sorry for that. It is supposed to be filterTable and not filterLinkTable.

Answer (score 2):

Well its better to use `computed` here instead of methods. I also renamed your function because there could be a problem with the names because they are the same:

```
computed: {
  filter_table() {
    return this.filterTable["domainValue"]
      ? this.links.filter(l => l.tag.domain === this.filterTable["domainValue"])
      : this.links.filter(
          l => l.post.indexed === this.filterTable["indexedValue"]
        );
  }
};

<tr v-for="(value, i) in filter_table" :key="value.id">
```

This should do the job.

You also dont need things like `var newLinks = this.links` you can directly go with `this.links.filter()`. Filter returns you a new array with the filtered values.

Edit:

You said you want to filter if both conditions are met:

```
computed: {
  filter_table() {
    return this.links.filter(
      (l) =>
        l.tag.domain === this.filterTable["domainValue"] &&
        l.post.indexed === this.filterTable["indexedValue"]
    );
};
```

Comment: Thank you! If I understand it correctly, the code above will filter based on either "domainValue" or "indexedValue" but not both. I would like to use both values to filter the table. That is why I used if-if and not if-else my code. is there a way to check whether multiple conditions are correct without the use of multiple if condition?

Comment: @Shinwi i dont get you. Do you mean you want to filter where `l.post.indexed === this.filterTable['indexedValue']` and `l.tag.domain === this.filterTable["domainValue"]`? only if those 2 conditions are met=

Comment: I would like for the conditions to be independent. If Condition 1 is true then apply that filter, if false do nothing. If Condition 2 is true then apply that filter otherwise do nothing. If both are true then apply both filters.